# 'DictReader' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

The first code gets me what I want, but not the second code, i am unable to understand difference between these two

```
for f in files:
    filename = (f[-10:-4])
    with open(f, 'r') as file:
        dr = csv.DictReader(file)
        to_db = [(filename,i['SC_CODE'],i['SC_NAME'],i['SC_GROUP'],i['SC_TYPE'],\
        i['OPEN'],i['HIGH'],i['LOW'],i['CLOSE'],i['LAST'],\
        i['PREVCLOSE'],i['NO_TRADES'],i['NO_OF_SHRS'],i['NET_TURNOV'],i['TDCLOINDI']\
        ) for i in dr]
```

following code throws an error "'DictReader' object is not subscriptable"

```
x = []
for f in files:
    filename = (f[-10:-4])
    with open(f, 'r') as file:
        dr = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in dr:
            x.append(str(filename),dr['SC_CODE'],dr['SC_NAME'],dr['SC_GROUP'],dr['SC_TYPE'],dr['OPEN'],dr['HIGH'],dr['LOW'],dr['CLOSE'],dr['LAST'],dr['PREVCLOSE'],dr['NO_TRADES'],dr['NO_OF_SHRS'],dr['NET_TURNOV'],dr['TDCLOINDI'])
```

Comment: i think it is because i have used dr instead of row in the append line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick glance, it looks like you should change `dir['SC_CODE']` etc to `row['SC_CODE']`, else you're iterating over the DictReader object for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

found the issue, here is the corrected code. I should  have used row and sq bracket like x.append([....]) instead of x.append(....)

```
for f in files:
    filename = (f[-10:-4])
    with open(f, 'r') as file:
        dr = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in dr:
            x.append([filename,row['SC_CODE'],row['SC_NAME'],row['SC_GROUP'],row['SC_TYPE'],row['OPEN'],row['HIGH'],row['LOW'],row['CLOSE'],row['LAST'],row['PREVCLOSE'],row['NO_TRADES'],row['NO_OF_SHRS'],row['NET_TURNOV'],row['TDCLOINDI']])
            print (row['SC_CODE'])`
```